# Could not find the main class cege.Main(). Program will exit

Tags: java, swing

I have a jar file and when I run it on a machine with no installed IntelliJ it gives me a message window saying:

```
Could not find the main class cege.Main(). Program will exit
```

And I used this site to create the jar file in IntelliJ: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Look at your jar file, perhaps with `jar tvvf file.jar`; then check that it has a class `cege.Main`.

Comment: class names cannot contain parentheses

Comment: Or name of class contains main method is different ...